# How to disable Auto Suggestion for Inventory ID field

Tags: acumatica

I would like to disable the auto suggestion for Inventory ID field in Materials screen. See this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `AutoComplete="False"` property to the editor control (row template):

```
<px:PXSegmentMask runat="server" ID="edInventoryID" DataField="InventoryID" CommitChanges="True" 
                  AutoComplete="False" />
```

I tested the property successfully on InventoryID field row template control (PXSegmentMask) in the Transactions tab/grid of the Sales Order screen.
[image]

Comment: Hello Hugues Beausejour, we successfully implemented this, but can we restrict this auto complete based on item class of Inventory Item. I mean, for one item class we do need auto complete to work as it is, but for one item class we don't need.

Comment: The auto complete results are based on the selector content of field, for this example field SOLine.InventoryID the selector is provided by attribute SOLineInventoryItemAttribute. You would need to replace that attribute with a copy of your own. In original attribute you can see filter in restrictor attribute: [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.noSales>,
       Or<Where<Current<SOOrderType.behavior>, Equal<SOOrderTypeConstants.salesOrder>,
        And<Current<SOOrderType.iNDocType>, Equal<INTranType.transfer>>>>>), IN.Messages.ItemCannotSale)]